# Algorithmic linear - log with While. Using big O

Tags: python, algorithm, while-loop

How is the complexity of algorithmic?.

I have the next sentences:

```
m = 12
while m>0:
  n = 0
  while n<m:
     n+=1 
  m/=3
```

I have that complexity is (n+1)(log_3(n)), so O(nlog_3(n) + log_3(n)) is the result.

this right?

Comment: O(nlog_3(n) + log_3(n))  =` O(n log n)`

Comment: What exactly is your input? `m`?  How did you get your result?

Comment: I need to get the degree of complexity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replacing m/=3 with m//=3 to ensure working with integer and removing side effects (the time needed for m/3 to round to 0), we can do some tests:

```
def counter(m):
    count = 0
    while m>0:
      count += 1
      n = 0
      while n<m:
         n+=1
         count += 1
      m//=3
    return count
```

Tests:

```
counter(12)
# 20
counter(1000)
# 1505
counter (1000000)
# 1500006
```

which points to a complexity of O(1.5 m).

The explanation if simple:
the number of iterations (for the inner loop, the number of iterations in the outer loop is negligible) is m + m/3 + m/3^2 + m/3^3 + ... , whose mathematical limit is m * 1/(1 - 1/3) = m * 1/(2/3) = 3m/2 .

2 final points:

- when evaluating complexity, you don't keep negligible (additive) elements.
- a complexity of O(1.5 m) will actually be written O(m) (linear complexity).

Comment: Hey! Thanks . I have a duda, the answer is in reference to `m/=3` or `m//=3` because I need to know  the complexity of my example:

Comment: In regards to your original example (with m/3), you have an additional (but globally constant, around 1300 from my tests; you can do tests yourself, just copy my script with counter and put back m/=3) number of loops before m is finally rounded to 0. This doesn't change the overall complexity, which is still O(m).

Comment: Thanks. If I have a duda, I hope to consult you

Answer (score -1):

The complexity is not O(nlog_3(n) + log_2(n)).
The outer loop runs until m becomes 0. The number of times the loop is executed is log_3(m).

Inside the loop, the inner loop runs n times, where n is the value of m at the start of each iteration of the outer loop.

The complexity of the algorithm is therefore O(m * log_3(m)).

Comment: That's not correct; there are side effects due to OP's not using integers, so the loop will be done a lot more than log_3(m) times; if however you replace m/=3 with m//=3 (euclidian division), the loop will be indeed effected ~log3(m) times, and the complexity will be O(3/2 m).

Comment: But your biggest error was forgetting m becomes lower and lower, so doing log3(m) * INITIAL value of m is erroneous.